# Rainbow-Colored Circular Lines on screen: Late 2012 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

**MY ISSUE:**

As the title reads, My MacBook pro, which can be seen here:

[image: MacBook Pro] is displaying a Rainbow-Colored circle that looks like something out of an Alien movie. Previous to this, I received a triple beep code associated with RAM issues. Other things to note: The battery was recently replaced and the screen is confirmed to have no issues. That's pretty much it. I have my thoughts on what the issue might be but decided to see if this is a common occurrence or if anyone had any experience dealing with something like this. I look forward to your commentary!

Answer (score 0):

Ive never seen a failure like that.  It looks like the GPU is failing, but Ive only ever seen vertical lines for that.  I would take it to Apple if it might be eligible for an extended warranty fix, but I wouldnt hold my breath.  They will most likely tell you to replace the entire machine.  You can try taking it to a reputable 3rd party repair company and see what they can do with it.

Comment: It is quiet an amusing failure, to say the least. I thought best case it could somehow be the RAM (because of previous issues with it), but that didn't seem logical to me. Worst case, I figured it was the GPU.